# Update all software with update manager XUbuntu 12.04.1 without updating kernel

Tags: 12.04, kernel, updates, ati, xubuntu

I'm running a laptop with mobility radeon hd 4330 and I have to run kernel <= 3.2 for the proprietary legacy drivers to work. How can I update the packages on my system using the update manager without automatically updating the kernel? I tried just installing all before, but then my kernel got updated.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an apt hold for this.

Running:

```
sudo apt-mark hold <package-name>
```

This will tell the system to hold that package at its current version no matter what.  Running:

```
sudo apt-mark hold linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Should hold the currently running kernel version. You can unhold it with `apt-mark unhold`.  Note that holding the kernel can cause unexpected consequences.

Comment: That's great thank you, but isn't there any way I can just select only the packages that won't affect the kernel? Unexpected consequences really wasn't what I was hoping for.

Comment: No I'm afraid there isn't a way to do that. I don't think you will have any problems at first, but eventually you will need to upgrade the kernel.

Comment: You mean in general or just if I hold the kernel? I really would like to stay on this kernel so I can use the proprietary driver so I could just not update most of the software. Would that be a problem?

Comment: @simernes That was mainly meant more as a disclaimer, I think it will work for a while but eventually something will happen.. An important package won't upgrade for example. That's all.